# Integrating Papplet in a tabbedPanel (application)

Tags: java, papplet

This is my first question at stackoverflow so if I miss information let me know.
I want to make a program which shows a worldmap in which you can zoom in and out and place marker which moves around (like a game map).
Because I would like the world map to be used offline I am using unfoldingmaps http://unfoldingmaps.org/.
This works great if I use the examples.
Now I would like to integrate this into the program I have already written.
I am trying to integrate the Papplet of the unfoldingmaps into a JPanel. This JPanel is part of a tabbedPanel.

This is the code I use to add it to the tabbedPanel:

```
    //Create game map menu
    gameMapMenu = new JPanel();
    tabbedPanelMain.addTab("World map", gameMapMenu);
    //tabbedPanelMain.setEnabledAt(2, false);
    worldMap = map.WorldMap.getWorldMap();
    gameMapMenu.add("World map", worldMap);
```

This is the code (in a separate Class) which is used to generate the unfolding map:

```
    UnfoldingMap map;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);

        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new MBTilesMapProvider(mbTilesString));
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
        map.setZoomRange(1, 10);
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        map.draw();
    }
    
    public static WorldMap getWorldMap() {
        WorldMap worldMap = new WorldMap();
        return worldMap;
    }
```

I have two questions I have been really struggling with and I cannot find any answers for:

1. The example above does not give any errors. It starts the application and tabbedPanel but does not show the map. If I run the Papplet of the world map in Eclipse as a Applet it works fine. How do I add the Papplet with the map to my existing application so it is viewed through the tabbedPanel?
2. To update the markers on the world map I was thinking about adding functions to the class with the worldmap Papplet. Is this the way to interact with the Papplet from the application?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying I found out I needed to add the `.init()` function.
Can someone explain to me what this does?

```
//Create game map menu
gameMapMenu = new JPanel();
tabbedPanelMain.addTab("World map", gameMapMenu);
tabbedPanelMain.setEnabledAt(2, false);
worldMap = map.WorldMap.getWorldMap();
gameMapMenu.add("World map", worldMap);
worldMap.init();
```